# "Error #2032: Stream Error" when loading a remote content

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to load a remote content from my web server using an `URLLoader` object.
For that, I used an [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#includeExamplesSummary) code from Adobe's help.

Here is what I tried :

```
var loader:URLLoader;

loader = new URLLoader();
configureListeners(loader);

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.fashionboxpk.com/Test2.php");
try
{
    loader.load(request);
}
catch (error:Error)
{
    trace("Unable to load requested document.");
}

function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void
{
    dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
    dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
    dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
    dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
    dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
}
function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    trace("completeHandler: " + loader.data);
}
function openHandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace("openHandler: " + event);
}
function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    trace("progressHandler loaded:" + event.bytesLoaded + " total: " + event.bytesTotal);
}
function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
}
function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void
{
    trace("httpStatusHandler: " + event);
}
function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
}
```

But when compiling, I got this output :

```
openHandler: [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
progressHandler loaded:384 total: 384
Error opening URL 'http://www.fashionboxpk.com/Test2.php'
httpStatusHandler: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=406 responseURL=null]
ioErrorHandler: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://www.fashionboxpk.com/Test2.php"]
```

So, how can I avoid those errors and load that content correctly ?

Comment: It looks that doesn't exist crossdomain.xml at [http://www.fashionboxpk.com/crossdomain.xml](http://www.fashionboxpk.com/crossdomain.xml)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) about who to ask good questions. Good questions get good answers here at SO. Bad questions tend to get ignored.

Comment: Is this a question??? Explain what you're **really** trying to achieve here... Using AS3 to open php page in browser tab? Or read php page content into AS3?

Comment: @MSafwan, your post is at risk of being deleted by admins because there is **no question**. It's nice that you pasted some text here but what is your **actual question**? Show the code sample that is giving you issues & explain what you want to achieve. After 3 years + months on StackOverflow, you should know how a good question is asked...

Comment: @MSafwanMemon I edited your question to be more readable, if there is something to add or edit you can use the "edit" link at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your crossdomain.xml is statingthat  only requests form your own domain are permitted (and you don't need a crossdomain.xml to read from your own domain anyways).

So if you are trying to test it locally by loading content from your server it won't work. Although I believe you should get a security sandbox violation error in this case.

And the HTTP Status you are getting says 406 ("Not acceptable"). So you might change your crossdomain so it allows requests from other domains or check your server settings if there is anything special regarding PHP files.

For the starts, test this as your crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Note that this allows any domain to send requests to your server and this is a serious security risk. This is fine for testing, but you should specify explicit domains here for the production system